# load a page in an element in another page onclick

Tags: javascript

I know the jQuery load syntax which is

```
$("#count").load("demo_test.txt #p1");
```

this is the code I'm using for my button's onclick function

```
temp_user_cart.php

    function resMinus(id){
        if (id) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "temp_cart-minus.php",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    id_minus: id
                },
                success:function(response) {
                    var employeeTable = $("#myTables").DataTable();
                    employeeTable.ajax.reload(null, false);

                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    };
```

After this AJAX succeed/execute I want to load the contents of cart_counter.php to this page

```
restaurant-order.php

<span id="cart_counter"></span>
```

this is cart_counter.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['count_count'];
?>
```

Comment: it seems you are selecting element in wrong way.  $("restaurant-order.php #cart_counter") would select nothing as there is no tag with this name 'restaurant-order.php'

Comment: @04FS I'm sorry, yes, jQuery. the problem/issue I'm having is that I want to load the contents of a page to another page after the AJAX succeeds. is it possible or am I chasing air on this one?

Comment: @sagar I'll update the question

Comment: _"I want to load the contents of a page to another page after the AJAX succeeds"_ - define "another page" - unless you are talking about one the user has currently open in a different tab (and you have a reference to that tab's window instance), then no, you can not do it this way.

Comment: You may do this by attaching the data with url as GET request. Issue is you always have to open the new url to get the content on other page.. another issue is it should never be your choice. Better you should load your page dynamically by requesting data from server. Otherwise, you are chasing air on this one.

Comment: @04FS I updated the question please have a look

Comment: @sagar I updated the question please have a look

Comment: You can not load anything "to" a page the user doesn't even have opened yet, you need to load that page itself first. And when you are doing that, it doesn't need an extra AJAX request to get the counter value - it is in the session, so the script `restaurant-order.php` can access it itself directly from there already. `<span id="cart_counter"><?php echo $_SESSION['count_count']; ?></span>`

Comment: @04FS the temp_user_cart.php is being loaded inside a modal in restaurant-order.php, so the restaurant-order.php is already opened

Comment: I'm trying to load the session variable because I want it to change whenever the the button is clicked

Comment: _"is being loaded inside a modal in restaurant-order.php"_ - well finally you've managed to give the crucial part of information you have been asked about ... _"so the restaurant-order.php is already opened"_ - not only that, you are in fact "on" that page already, so `<span id="cart_counter">` exists in the _current_ document. So what is the problem then, you _know_ the necessary syntax, it is the very first line of code you presented here.

Comment: (Still doesn't change the fact that `temp_cart-minus.php` should return the current counter value directly upon that first POST request you are making. This does absolutely not need a _second_ request.)

Comment: sorry, I'm pretty slow on the uptake there. how should I do it so that it will return the the value on first post?

Comment: You have temp_cart-minus.php echo back the current counter value after it has altered it, and then you place the response of that request (that you are currently not doing anything with) into the span element inside your success handler - `$('#cart_counter').text(response);`